# Saving related objects in SubSonic

Tags: subsonic

I have 2 tables, Order and OrderItem, which have a 1-many relationship.

When I am adding a new order at the front end, how to I create the relationship. E.g.

```
(Order and OrderItem generated by SubSonic).
Order order = new Order();
//populate order details.


OrderItem item = new OrderItem();
//populate orderItem details.
```

How do I then set the relationship so that when I save them to the database they will store the correct foreign key values, something along the lines of

```
item.setParent(order);
```

EDIT:

I tried using

```
order.OrderItemRecords().Add(item);
```

but still getting error when I update DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(Order and OrderItem generated by SubSonic).
Order order = new Order();
//populate order details.


OrderItem item = new OrderItem();
//populate orderItem details.

item.Order = order;   //THIS LINE SETS THE PARENT OBJECT TO ABOVE ORDER
```

Just remember to wrap up in a transaction and call the save methods to commit this info to your database. You will have add a reference to the System.Transactions namespace in your project and then reference in your class.

e.g

```
   using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            Order order = new Order();
            //populate order details.
            order.Save(); //Commit to DB


            OrderItem item = new OrderItem();
            //populate orderItem details.

            item.Order = order;   //THIS LINE SETS THE PARENT OBJECT TO ABOVE ORDER

            item.Save();  //Commit to DB

            //complete you transaction
            scope.Complete();

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```